# ANR - Input dispatching timed out - Android 11

Tags: android

My app gets ANR error only on android 11 devices. Input dispatching timed out means that main thread got stuck in a loop but based on my logcat trace what i understand is that there is a problem with `file.exists()` line.

Here is my logcat trace

```
at libcore.io.Linux.access (Native method)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access (ForwardingOs.java:72)
  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access (BlockGuardOs.java:73)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access (ForwardingOs.java:72)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access (ActivityThread.java:7937)
  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess (UnixFileSystem.java:281)
  at java.io.File.exists (File.java:815)
  at com.****************.FileUtils.fileIsExists (FileUtils.java:17)
```

and here my FileUtlis.class

```
public class FileUtils {
    public static boolean fileIsExists(String path) {
        if (path == null || path.trim().length() <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            File f = new File(path);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same here when access file from directory, and only in Android 11 devices....did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Put MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE flag in Manifest. Prompt user to allow all files access by opening the settings with ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION intent. Give that permission